# Replace creplace @ to %40 in my forder path in batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to replace `@` to `%40` in my forder path:

```
@ECHO OFF
set filepath= x:\Test\Test\Test\Test\@Test\@Test\@Test\@Test\Test\Test.mov

set string=%filepath%
set string=%string:@=%40%

set folder=%string%
echo %folder%
pause
```

I need:

> ```
> x:\Test\Test\Test\Test\@Test\@Test\@Test\@Test\Test\Test.mov
> x:\Test\Test\Test\Test\%40Test\%40Test\%40Test\%40Test\Test\Test.mov
> ```

Like this; can anybody please help me how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cases such as this delayed expansion comes in handy and because you're using a batch file the **`%`** needs to be doubled.

```bat
@Echo Off

Set "filepath=x:\Test\Test\Test\Test\@Test\@Test\@Test\@Test\Test\Test.mov"

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "folder=!filepath:@=%%40!
EndLocal & Echo %folder%
Pause
```